# How to get direct download URL link for directory in Google Disk?

Tags: google-drive

I know how to create a link from shared file

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing
```

to direct download link

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

However, I can't find a solution for directory direct download link? I have something like this

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/FOLDER_ID?usp=sharing
```

and this doesn't work.

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FOLDER_ID
```

I would like to have a link for directory which would compress all files and directories in it as one zip file like it does when downloading manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, a folder cannot be downloaded with the direct download link.

Such a folder needs to be firstly zipped e.g. zip = file = you can then use `FILE_ID` and after you get share link of that zip, you can then `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID` it.